# Craft 4 install error at craft/migrations/install

Tags: installation, craft4

I'm trying to install a fresh copy of Craft 4.

The following error:

```
message: "An error occurred while executing the \"craft\\migrations\\Install migration: rename(): The first argument to copy() function cannot be a directory"
```

returned by the endpoint

```
/index.php?p=admin%2Factions%2Finstall%2Finstall&v=.....
```

After scouring the internet for an answer, I'm hopelessly lost as to why this error is thrown.

In my `composer.json`, I have  `"craftcms/cms": "^4.0.0.1",` and the whole thing is launched from a container based on `craftcms/nginx:8.0`.

Has anyone seen this before?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you find the full stack trace leading up to the error in the Craft `storage/logs` folder and edit the original question to share it?

Comment: We solved this, the issue was the presence an existing config/project folder, that remained after a test install locally. Removing this folder solved the issue. Thanks for the attention tho! :)

Comment: Ahh... glad you're all sorted! Want to add that as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future?